Short story about a computer that corrects Shakespeare
I read this SF story at least 3 or 4 decades ago, and it was much older than that. I read it in English and probably in some collection because I rarely read magazines, but I have no idea what collection it was.
Its premise, which by now is not SF anymore, but was at the time it was written, is that there exists one (or maybe several) computer(s) which can understand written text and analyse it. It is the same premise as that of my still unanswered question about a novel in French and also in Asimov's Foundation, but it is neither of them. It is not a novel, but a short story (or just possibly a short novelette).
There is also an extra element absent in the others. Having analysed the beginning of a text, the computer can continue writing, using consistency based on the beginning. If the author is a good one, claim the creators of the computer, then his text will coincide with what the computer continues. If not, it means that the author is inconsistent.
IIRC, they try it on a few poetries, from celebrated authors, and it works well : the people who have been invited to witness the prowess of the computer are duly impressed.
Then the computer is tried on Shakespeare (IIRC, Hamlet's monologue) and changes the text : it finds an inconsistency ! This was its downfall : certainly Shakespeare knew of the inconsistency, and wrote it anyway, because he was a genius and did what he considered best. No computer cannot equal a genius.

It's one of the golden agers, Asimov or the like.

https://www.reddit.com/r/asimov/comments/11zz7lp/did_asimov_predict_gpt4/

The Monkey's Finger by Asimov.
It's been on this forum a few times. See previous answers for details.
Story about automatic writing machine in a dispute between writer and editor
Identify the story about an author whose work-in-progress is completed by a computer
